# Check if a particular value is a datetime and assigning a particular column value in pandas

Tags: pandas, data-imputation

I have a pandas data frame that contains a partially corrupted data field as below. It has numbers (which are not a date) or nans. The real data frame has an incredibly large number of rows as well. I want to take the non-date values in this and assigning them to the date closest to it row-wise. For example, if the date field in row 3 is a nan or a junk value (a number or a string), I want the date in row 3 to be equal to the date in row 2 or row 4. Is there a way to do this that doesn't involve iterating over the entire data frame in a for loop?

```
inputArr = [['A', Timestamp('2021-06-01 00:00:00'), 9],
 ['A', Timestamp('2021-06-01 00:00:00'), 60],
 ['A', Timestamp('2021-06-01 00:00:00'), 39],
 ['A', 3, 51],
 ['A', Timestamp('2021-06-01 00:00:00'), 99],
 ['B', Timestamp('2021-06-01 00:00:00'), 21],
 ['B', Timestamp('2021-06-01 00:00:00'), 93],
 ['B', Timestamp('2021-06-01 00:00:00'), 42],
 ['B', 'xpwh1i3992aisan', 87],
 ['B', Timestamp('2021-06-01 00:00:00'), 33],
 ['C', nan, 72],
 ['C', Timestamp('2021-06-01 00:00:00'), 90],
 ['C', Timestamp('2021-06-01 00:00:00'), 42],
 ['C', 3, 87],
 ['C', 'items 44', 30],
 ['D', Timestamp('2021-06-01 00:00:00'), 75],
 ['D', Timestamp('2021-06-01 00:00:00'), 87],
 ['D', Timestamp('2021-06-01 00:00:00'), 78],
 ['D', 3, 75],
 ['D', Timestamp('2021-06-01 00:00:00'), 60],
 ['E', Timestamp('2021-06-01 00:00:00'), 0],
 ['E', nan, 69],
 ['E', Timestamp('2021-06-01 00:00:00'), 21],
 ['E', 3, 30],
 ['E', Timestamp('2021-06-01 00:00:00'), 69]]

trialPD = pd.DataFrame(inputArr, columns = ["Name", "date_purchase", "num_items"])
```

Comment: Should be easily achievable. You may need to make all Non-Timestamp values to NaN, and do a Timestamp imputation in Pandas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
import datetime

trialPD["date_purchase"].apply(lambda x: x if isinstance(x,datetime.datetime) else np.nan).fillna(method = "ffill")
```

Answer (score 2):

Also this is a simple one:

```
trialPD['date_purchase'] = pd.to_datetime(trialPD['date_purchase'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', errors='coerce').ffill()
```